# Windows 7 Network Places do not show local computers

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My Windows 7 Network Places do not show local network computers since about one month ago.

I tried turning on *Network Discovery* in *Network and Sharing Center* by changing advanced sharing settings.

My PC is in `WorkGroup` connected wirelessly through a router. Other computers are also running Windows 7.

Other computers can see my PC and they access my shared folder, only my computer can't see them – even through the command line with `\\ip` or `pcname` I can't access it. Through `cmd` I can ping them though.

I think it may be caused by a virus. Because when I share a folder, a "Your folder can't be shared" message occurs, but actually it was shared.

Comment: So, if you think it's a virus, did you scan for viruses?